# org.hibernate.criterion.Example use with CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-5.x

I have following code that I need to refactor for use in hibernate 5. This includes removing every deprecated call.

```
public List<T> findByExample(T example, String... excludeProperty) {   
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(T.class);
    Example ex = Example.create(example);
    for (String exclude : excludeProperty) {
        ex.excludeProperty(exclude);
    }
    crit.add(ex);
    return crit.list();
}
```

Since `createCriteria` is deprecated I was going to replace it with `getSession().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Foo.class);`. This is in theory the right way to do it, but now I have no idea how to go about the `Example` and how it is used in the code.

**Can anyone help me to use the `Example` with hibernate 5?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: None using `Example`. I did create a workaround using reflection. Though my solution has been enhanced by colleague lately

Comment: Alright, just as I thought, thanks. The Example was not much more than reflection anyways, as far as I know. Any chance to post your solution as an answer to this question? Otherwise, I can post mine when it is finished, but it will take some time.

Comment: Hasn't this become more urgent for many of us since the arrival of Spring Boot 3, containing the update to Hibernate 6? A solution without Example is needed - does anybody have one?